# Is there something wrong with my while loops? My code syntax? Is it just too much?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop, calendar

I'm trying to build a dynamic database-driven calendar application. I'm in step 1, trying to set up the calendar. Instead of entering it all in manually, I thought I'd take a shortcut and make a PHP script to add it all into my databases.

The problem is, my script involves a lot of while loops. It's taking forever to load. Could it just take a while to execute the script, or is there an error somewhere? Is there an easier way to make a calendar?

**EDIT: I have all of my database configuration in another block before this block. That is not the problem.**

**EDIT 2: I noticed some of my SQL contained reserved keywords. I changed those to different words.**

Here is my code:

```
    <?php


       $calsql = "SELECT * FROM callender";

       $calquery = mysqli_query($db,$calsql);

       $calisfull = mysqli_num_rows($calquery);

       if ($calisfull < 1) {
        while ($all < 365) {
                $year = "2016";
                $month = 1;
                if ($month == 1){

                    $dayofmonth = 1;
                    while ($dayofmonth < 32) {
                        $d = 0;
                        while ($d < 7) {
                            if ($d == 0){
                                $day = "Friday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 1){
                                $day = "Saturday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 2){
                                $day = "Sunday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 3){
                                $day = "Monday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 4){
                                $day = "Tuesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 5){
                                $day = "Wednesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 6){
                                $day = "Thursday";
                            }

                        $fillsql = "INSERT INTO callender (month, date, year, day) VALUES ('$month', '$dayofmonth', '$year', '$day')";
                        $fquery = mysqli_query($db,$fillsql);
                        $perfectly = "Perfectly";
                        $dayofmonth++;
                        $all++;
                    }

                    $d = 0;
                }
                $month++;
            }
                if ($month == 2){

                    $dayofmonth = 1;
                    while ($dayofmonth < 30) {
                        while ($d < 7) {
                            if ($d == 0){
                                $day = "Friday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 1){
                                $day = "Saturday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 2){
                                $day = "Sunday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 3){
                                $day = "Monday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 4){
                                $day = "Tuesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 5){
                                $day = "Wednesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 6){
                                $day = "Thursday";
                            }

                        $fillsql = "INSERT INTO callender (month, date, year, day) VALUES ('$month', '$dayofmonth', '$year', '$day')";
                        $fquery = mysqli_query($db,$fillsql);
                        $perfectly = "Perfectly";
                        $dayofmonth++;
                        $all++;
                    }

                    $d = 0;
                }
                $month++;
            }
                if ($month == 3){

                    $dayofmonth = 1;
                    while ($dayofmonth < 32) {
                        while ($d < 7) {
                            if ($d == 0){
                                $day = "Friday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 1){
                                $day = "Saturday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 2){
                                $day = "Sunday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 3){
                                $day = "Monday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 4){
                                $day = "Tuesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 5){
                                $day = "Wednesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 6){
                                $day = "Thursday";
                            }

                        $fillsql = "INSERT INTO callender (month, date, year, day) VALUES ('$month', '$dayofmonth', '$year', '$day')";
                        $fquery = mysqli_query($db,$fillsql);
                        $perfectly = "Perfectly";
                        $dayofmonth++;
                        $all++;
                    }

                    $d = 0;
                }
                $month++;
            }
                if ($month == 4){

                    $dayofmonth = 1;
                    while ($dayofmonth < 31) {
                        while ($d < 7) {
                            if ($d == 0){
                                $day = "Friday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 1){
                                $day = "Saturday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 2){
                                $day = "Sunday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 3){
                                $day = "Monday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 4){
                                $day = "Tuesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 5){
                                $day = "Wednesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 6){
                                $day = "Thursday";
                            }

                        $fillsql = "INSERT INTO callender (month, date, year, day) VALUES ('$month', '$dayofmonth', '$year', '$day')";
                        $fquery = mysqli_query($db,$fillsql);
                        $perfectly = "Perfectly";
                        $dayofmonth++;
                        $all++;
                    }

                    $d = 0;
                }
                $month++;
            }
                if ($month == 5){

                    $dayofmonth = 1;
                    while ($dayofmonth < 31) {
                        while ($d < 7) {
                            if ($d == 0){
                                $day = "Friday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 1){
                                $day = "Saturday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 2){
                                $day = "Sunday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 3){
                                $day = "Monday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 4){
                                $day = "Tuesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 5){
                                $day = "Wednesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 6){
                                $day = "Thursday";
                            }

                        $fillsql = "INSERT INTO callender (month, date, year, day) VALUES ('$month', '$dayofmonth', '$year', '$day')";
                        $fquery = mysqli_query($db,$fillsql);
                        $perfectly = "Perfectly";
                        $dayofmonth++;
                        $all++;
                    }

                    $d = 0;
                }
                $month++;
            }
                if ($month == 6){

                    $dayofmonth = 1;
                    while ($dayofmonth < 31) {
                        while ($d < 7) {
                            if ($d == 0){
                                $day = "Friday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 1){
                                $day = "Saturday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 2){
                                $day = "Sunday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 3){
                                $day = "Monday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 4){
                                $day = "Tuesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 5){
                                $day = "Wednesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 6){
                                $day = "Thursday";
                            }

                        $fillsql = "INSERT INTO callender (month, date, year, day) VALUES ('$month', '$dayofmonth', '$year', '$day')";
                        $fquery = mysqli_query($db,$fillsql);
                        $perfectly = "Perfectly";
                        $dayofmonth++;
                        $all++;
                    }

                    $d = 0;
                }
                $month++;
            }
                if ($month == 7){

                    $dayofmonth = 1;
                    while ($dayofmonth < 32) {
                        while ($d < 7) {
                            if ($d == 0){
                                $day = "Friday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 1){
                                $day = "Saturday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 2){
                                $day = "Sunday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 3){
                                $day = "Monday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 4){
                                $day = "Tuesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 5){
                                $day = "Wednesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 6){
                                $day = "Thursday";
                            }

                        $fillsql = "INSERT INTO callender (month, date, year, day) VALUES ('$month', '$dayofmonth', '$year', '$day')";
                        $fquery = mysqli_query($db,$fillsql);
                        $perfectly = "Perfectly";
                        $dayofmonth++;
                        $all++;
                    }

                    $d = 0;
                }
                $month++;
            }
                if ($month == 8){

                    $dayofmonth = 1;
                    while ($dayofmonth < 32) {
                        while ($d < 7) {
                            if ($d == 0){
                                $day = "Friday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 1){
                                $day = "Saturday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 2){
                                $day = "Sunday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 3){
                                $day = "Monday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 4){
                                $day = "Tuesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 5){
                                $day = "Wednesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 6){
                                $day = "Thursday";
                            }

                        $fillsql = "INSERT INTO callender (month, date, year, day) VALUES ('$month', '$dayofmonth', '$year', '$day')";
                        $fquery = mysqli_query($db,$fillsql);
                        $perfectly = "Perfectly";
                        $dayofmonth++;
                        $all++;
                    }

                    $d = 0;
                }
                $month++;
            }
                if ($month == 9){

                    $dayofmonth = 1;
                    while ($dayofmonth < 31) {
                        while ($d < 7) {
                            if ($d == 0){
                                $day = "Friday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 1){
                                $day = "Saturday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 2){
                                $day = "Sunday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 3){
                                $day = "Monday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 4){
                                $day = "Tuesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 5){
                                $day = "Wednesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 6){
                                $day = "Thursday";
                            }

                        $fillsql = "INSERT INTO callender (month, date, year, day) VALUES ('$month', '$dayofmonth', '$year', '$day')";
                        $fquery = mysqli_query($db,$fillsql);
                        $perfectly = "Perfectly";
                        $dayofmonth++;
                        $all++;
                    }

                    $d = 0;
                }
                $month++;
            }
                if ($month == 10){

                    $dayofmonth = 1;
                    while ($dayofmonth < 32) {
                        while ($d < 7) {
                            if ($d == 0){
                                $day = "Friday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 1){
                                $day = "Saturday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 2){
                                $day = "Sunday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 3){
                                $day = "Monday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 4){
                                $day = "Tuesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 5){
                                $day = "Wednesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 6){
                                $day = "Thursday";
                            }

                        $fillsql = "INSERT INTO callender (month, date, year, day) VALUES ('$month', '$dayofmonth', '$year', '$day')";
                        $fquery = mysqli_query($db,$fillsql);
                        $perfectly = "Perfectly";
                        $dayofmonth++;
                        $all++;
                    }

                    $d = 0;
                }
            }
                if ($month == 11){

                    $dayofmonth = 1;
                    while ($dayofmonth < 31) {
                        while ($d < 7) {
                            if ($d == 0){
                                $day = "Friday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 1){
                                $day = "Saturday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 2){
                                $day = "Sunday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 3){
                                $day = "Monday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 4){
                                $day = "Tuesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 5){
                                $day = "Wednesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 6){
                                $day = "Thursday";
                            }

                        $fillsql = "INSERT INTO callender (month, date, year, day) VALUES ('$month', '$dayofmonth', '$year', '$day')";
                        $fquery = mysqli_query($db,$fillsql);
                        $perfectly = "Perfectly";
                        $dayofmonth++;
                        $all++;
                    }

                    $d = 0;
                }
                $month++;
            }
                if ($month == 12){

                    $dayofmonth = 1;
                    while ($dayofmonth < 32) {
                        while ($d < 7) {
                            if ($d == 0){
                                $day = "Friday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 1){
                                $day = "Saturday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 2){
                                $day = "Sunday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 3){
                                $day = "Monday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 4){
                                $day = "Tuesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 5){
                                $day = "Wednesday";
                            }

                            else if ($d == 6){
                                $day = "Thursday";
                            }

                        $fillsql = "INSERT INTO callender (month, date, year, day) VALUES ('$month', '$dayofmonth', '$year', '$day')";
                        $fquery = mysqli_query($db,$fillsql);
                        $perfectly = "Perfectly";
                        $dayofmonth++;
                        $all++;
                    }

                    $d = 0;
                }
                $month++;
            }
        }

       }

       echo "Code worked " . $perfectly;

       ?>
```

Comment: dont separate date components(store y-m-d) together this will make db functions a lot easier. i wouldn't prefill a db like this, its not a spread sheet, dont store dates unless you need them.

Comment: whats `$all` at `while ($all < 365) `

Comment: You should always use a prepared statement. It will allow your database to only use one query and just swap out the values as you loop.

Comment: Also, consider making a function. You're repeating way too much code.

Comment: What is `date` in your queries? We don't see where it comes from

Comment: And don't have columns for year, month, and day

Comment: @BeetleJuice date is filled by the $dayofmonth variable.

Comment: @Strawberry I already noticed that. Changed it, and it didn't help.

Comment: @4castle I'm putting in functions now.

Comment: @ChrysUgwu I just defined $all to 0. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I think the entire approach is wrong-headed. PHP is perfectly capable of spitting out a calendar without recourse to a database. So all you need to store is the event, and the significant date upon which it occurs/commences.

Comment: @Dagon I'm going to have another script after this one that draws from the database and uses the values to put together the HTML of the calendar. It's a multi-step process. I'm just trying to automate all the tedious typing.

Comment: @IanJ ok if by `$dayofmonth` you mean '01' to '31', I've adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: still please use a proper date field in the db, it ill be much easier to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is taking a long time because you're executing 365 queries when you could be executing just one. You also don't need to hard code values for each month for each day of the week. Below I've collapsed your huge loop into two lines of code:

```
$start = strtotime('2016-01-01');
$end = strtotime('2016-12-31');
$current = $start;
$rows =[];

while ($current <=$end){
    //insert eg: ('1', '31', '2016', 'Sunday') for Jan 31 2016.
    $rows[] = strftime("('%m', '%d', '%Y', '%A')",$current);
    $current = strtotime('+1 day',$current); //to next day
}
//build one combined query
$sql='INSERT into callender (month, date, year, day) VALUES '.implode(',',$rows);
$fquery = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

if(!$fquery) die('DB error: '.mysqli_error($db));

echo 'Success: '.mysqli_num_rows($fquery).' rows inserted';
```

Checkout two of PHP's most awesome functions:

- [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) turns human-readable strings into UNIX timestamp
- [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) turns a UNIX timestamp into a date string in the format of your choice

Now that the solution is out of the way: there is a bigger problem with this approach. It's a waste of DB space and resources to store dates because they can be calculated on the fly faster than it would take to retrieve them from the database.  You can adapt the code above to make a function that takes `$startDate`, `$endDate` and returns an array with all calendar entries to print into your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very complicated and long. Only few notes for improving. You can define names of months and days in array and then access to names via array index.
Arrays define like

```
$monthNames = array(1 => 'January', 'February',..., 'December');

$dayNames = array(1 => 'Monday', 'Tuesday',...,'Sunday');
```

Furthermore is good to use PHP function [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), you can find out via this function which day of week is, how many days in concrete month and many others useful informations. 
Other useful function for your purpose is [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php).
You can find out day of the week e.g. this way

```
$dayOfTheWeek = date('N', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
```

Number of days in month e.g. this way

```
$daysInSelectedMonth = date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
```

Other things are for self study:-)

Answer (score 0):

You most likely don't need to add an entry in the database for each and every day of the year if all you want to know is which day of the week corresponds to a specific date.

Both [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) have means to represent dates and times as variables, and functions that allow you to operate with them.

Examples:

Is 2016 a leap year?

PHP:

```
<?php
$year = 2016;
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setDate($year, 3, 1);
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
if($date->format("d") == "29") {
    print "$year is leap";
} else {
    print "$year is not leap";
}
```

MySQL:

```
> select (dayofmonth(date_sub('2016-03-01', interval 1 day)) = 29) as isleap;
+--------+
| isleap |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
```

What's the day of the week?

PHP:

```
print $date->format("w"); // 0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday
print $date->format("l"); // in English
```

MySQL:

```
select dayofweek(mydate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your db request into one. Has well you may want to change your php script execution time in php.ini or use the php set command to adjust it at the start of the script (for a per script only bases)